# edgebundleR: define the nodes order and a gap between nodes "groups"

Tags: r

I have a circle plot made in R using the [edgebundleR](https://github.com/garthtarr/edgebundleR) package representing a countries collaboration network. I would like to know if is it possible define the nodes order and a space between node groups (representing the continents) in the plot?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding to the nodes name the corresponding continent name separated by a ".". The nodes sharing the same continent name are automatically grouped in the plot.